# Php include, index.php and CSS file problems

Tags: php, css, hyperlink, indexing

Hello guys can anyone tell me how this code works:

```
<?php 
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "pages/include/headertop.php";
   include_once($path);
?>
```

Someone recommended this to me. Since I have trouble with my include files when I transferred it inside the sub-folder/directories:

```
pages/include/headertop.php
```

Another problem is that the CSS linked to the include files don't work with the `index.php` file since I've transferred the include file to the sub-folders.

These codes below works half-way actually. Problem is that the CSS is not working with it. And if I relink the CSS for the index.php file, the files left in the subfolders gets messed up because of the redirected links.

```
<?php
include ("pages/include/headertop.php");
include ("pages/include/header.php"); 
include ("pages/include/nav.php");
?>
```

By the way, my `index.php` file is in the root directory/main folder.

Thanks guys! I really need your help.

Comment: In which of the files is <head></head>?

Comment: The index.php has a <head></head> tags

Answer (score 0):

I think $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] returns no slash add the end. So your $path is missing a trailing slash.

Maybe this works?

```
$path .= "/pages/include/headertop.php";
```

Comment: Thanks Bernhard. It still doesn't work. Actually I only have a major issue with css. This one works already: <?php include ("pages/include/heardertop.hph"); ?> Now the CSS of headertop.php is in the subfolder. This only works if I relink the headertop.php CSS. Which I cannot since this would mess up the other pages using the the same link. The index.php is the only file in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER` is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. it defines the path to a file

 and
**'DOCUMENT_ROOT'**
The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.
detail [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) 

after
that you have added the path to your folder

```
$path .= "pages/include/headertop.php";
```

and at the end 
`include_once` is added to eliminate duplication of included file.

Comment: Nice. Thanks! But why is is not working for me. My index.php file is the only file that is still messed up that rest is ok. I'm using the include file (headertop.php - which is a constant) in the index.php. Any suggestions?

Comment: is your index file and other file are is in same directory?

Comment: can you give us your index code and more brief cause I can't understand your problem

Comment: Nope. index.php is the only file that is in the main folder. The rest is segregated in the sub folder including css.

Comment: I want things in order. So I placed them in the respective folder. Previously, they are in just one directory - in the main folder/root directory. Now I made folders of them.

Comment: okay you add all your external file in a single file and include this file in index.php am i right?

Comment: Not really. I have a folder for the include files, css files, images files, pages files, javascript files etc... except for the index.php file which is outside these folders. In other words, it's in the main folder together with the sub-folders. Now I'm linking some of these sub-folder files to the index.php file. These files include the css and the include files which contain css inside it. For example: headertop.hph has css inside it that is being shared by every pages of my site, since headertop.php is a constant.

Comment: The problem is the index.php requires that the css link of the headertop.php should be relinked to its path for it to work. Now if I do that, the sub-folder files using/sharing those css link will get messed-up. Any suggestion again? Thanks!

Comment: I think you have add you css in more then one file open your file in localhost and press (ctrl+u) then you will see all the files you have included in your index.php and check by clicking on these files are they working or not and check if you have add file twice!

Comment: Yup, I have checked. And everything else is working perfectly. Except for the index.php page because of the include file which I transferred recently. I cannot put index.php file the subfolder obviously or put the include file together with the index file since I'm cleaning up the clatter.

Comment: The only concern is the link of the CSS towards the constant (header.php, headertop.php, nav.php and footer.php) to index.php file. I cannot modify the link since the subfolder is using the same link. So, it will get messed up if I relink the css towards the index.php